# Using Eclipse 3.7 for developing Plugin based on Eclipse RCP 3.5

Tags: eclipse, target, rcp, platform

is it possible to use Eclipse 3.7 IDE for developing for the 3.5 platform? Or must I use Eclipse 3.5 IDE?

When I try to switch from Eclipse 3.5 IDE to 3.7 I get errors on projects, which were ok before:
Archive for required library: 'C:/.../.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.pde.core/.external_libraries/xyz/os/win32/x86' in project 'projectname' cannot be read or is not a valid ZIP file  projectname

What do I have to do to exchange the 3.5 IDE with a current one, but still develop for the 3.5 platform?

I hope my explanation did make sense and was understandable :)

Additional Info:
- I never used the RCP before, now I must use it
- It's no option to upgrade the target platform (3.5)
- I searched the net and stackoverflow, but found no answers for using 3.7 and develop for target platform 3.5 (maybe nobody else has these problems or I used the wrong queries)

Cheers
Kai

Comment: Seems like Stackoverflow lost my "Hi, ..." at the beginning of the post - and edit seems to not work for 're-adding' it... sorry for this - and HELLO to all :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just resolved my problem :-)

In my case, there was a plugin jar, that contained the java sources:

```
jar
    com
    META-INF
    src
    plugin.xml
```

It seems like eclipse is putting jars inside of plugin jars in the following directory:

```
[WORKSPACE]\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.pde.core\.external_libraries\...
```

For my plugin, it tried to put the `src` folder in this directory - which somehow failed.

After deleting the `src` folder inside the jar, the errors were gone.

RCP == bag of pain :-)

Answer (score 1):

Use the menu 
Window > Preferences:
Plug-in development > target platform

Here you can add your eclipse 3.5 as a target platform, and then set it active.

But I don't think this will solve the errors you mentioned. I think those errors are because you are using the old workspace folder, and there is something not compatible with eclipse3.7.  So maybe you can try to switch to a new workspace, and import your projects there.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I created a totally new workspace and imported the projects into the new workspace. After setting the target plattform, cleaning all projects, reloading the target platform,... I still get the above mentioned error and can not build. Maybe Eclipse can see, that I think low of the RCP and and bugs me therefore :)